# C++ Why does this piece of code work that concurrently writes to a vector in multiple threads? It doesn't get corrupted

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, memory-management

Note: This is compiled with `GCC 11.2.0`

The following is supposed to be a simplified example of my more complicated code. My actual code is too complicated to explain, so I tried to create a simple reproducible version of the problem, but it actually worked. And now aside from my code, I'm more interested in why this simple example even works.

Basically, I'm creating a vector of maps. The number of maps depends on the number of threads I'm running. Each thread will populate each map in the vector. I expected that since the vector is being written to by multiple threads at the same time, it should have corrupted data because it's all contiguous memory, that changes dynamically at run-time, right? So how does this not have corrupted data?

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP  //add it top of c++ code
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <thread>

void add_map(std::unordered_map<int, int>& um, int map_size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < map_size; i++) {
    um.insert({i, i});
  }
}

void print_map(std::unordered_map<int, int>& um) {
  for (auto& u : um) { std::cout << u.first << " " << u.second << std::endl; }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Get number of threads from user input and set random seed
  int num_threads = std::stoi(argv[1]);
  std::srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

  // Populate a vector with num_threads maps, so each trhead can write to each map inside the vector
  std::vector<std::unordered_map<int, int>> chunks;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> empty_map;
    chunks.push_back(empty_map);
  }

  // Come up with the sizes for each map that will be handled by each thread
  std::vector<int> chunk_sizes;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    int chunk_size = 1 + (std::rand() % 5);
    chunk_sizes.push_back(chunk_size);
  }
  std::cout << "Chunk sizes" << std::endl; for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) { std::cout << chunk_sizes[i] << " "; } std::cout << std::endl;

  // For each thread, create a <int, int> unordered map so that the parts of the vector 'chunks' gets populated concurrently
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    threads.push_back(std::thread(add_map, std::ref(chunks[i]), chunk_sizes[i]));
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) { threads[i].join(); }

  // Print the maps
  for (int i = 0; i < chunks.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << "=== chunk: " << i << "; size: " << chunk_sizes[i] << " ===" << std::endl;
    print_map(chunks[i]);
  }
}
```

When run with an argument of `5`, I get the following output

```
Chunk sizes
2 5 5 4 4
=== chunk: 0; size: 2 ===
1 1
0 0
=== chunk: 1; size: 5 ===
4 4
3 3
2 2
1 1
0 0
=== chunk: 2; size: 5 ===
4 4
3 3
2 2
1 1
0 0
=== chunk: 3; size: 4 ===
3 3
2 2
1 1
0 0
=== chunk: 4; size: 4 ===
3 3
2 2
1 1
0 0
```

Looks like the vector of maps is being handled as expected. But why?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be? It's legal for different threads to access or modify different elements of a vector. There's no race.

Comment: Totally unrelated: `chunks.push_back(empty_map);` could be `chunks.emplace_back();` and `empty_map` vanishes forever.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm sorry for my ignorance. The way I understand it, a vector is one continuous chunk of memory that gets expanded as needed. So with  multiple threads writing to it, it could be writing, or copying data into a larger chunk of memory as it expands, etc.... And I thought this would cause the data to be corrupted.

Comment: Agree with Igor. Looks like you oversimplified and accidentally eliminated the bug in your larger code. This can be a good thing. You may be able to use this as a baseline to build back up to the more complicated code, but without the mistake that's giving you grief.

Comment: If you were to add elements to the vector in multiple threads, that'd be a problem. But you don't - nothing is being "expanded as needed". All the expansion happened in `main` before the worker threads started.

Comment: The `vector` is unchanged. Each of its elements is a `unordered_map` and those maps change without ever being shared with other threads.

Comment: The data of the maps is not stored in the vector. Adding values to the maps doesn't change the size or memory of the vector.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. I'm so sorry but could you please help me understand how? If I fill it with empty maps, and say 10 threads. It'll create 10 empty maps, which takes up some amount of space. But as each thread writes to each map, the overall vector size grows, right? And as a vector grows past some capacity, it needs to reallocate a larger part of memory somewhere else. And during that reallocation, if it's still writing from some other thread, something should go wrong. Am i misunderstanding something here?

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: _"But as each thread writes to each map, the overall vector size grows, right?"_ Wrong. _"The data of the maps is not stored in the vector. Adding values to the maps doesn't change the size or memory of the vector."_ _"Am i misunderstanding something here?"_ Yes, you're misunderstanding, how containers store the data.

Comment: @jabaa Oh. So is each element of a vector just a pointer to a map so that each map is in a different part of memory?

Comment: `sizeof(std::unordered_map<int, int>)` is a compile-time constant. It doesn't depend on the number of elements the map happens to store at run-time.

Comment: _"So is each element of a vector just a pointer to a map so that each map is in a different part of memory?"_ It's not completely correct, but you can simplify it like that: The vector contains a pointer to its data. The maps are stored in the data of the vector, but the maps contain pointers to different locations in memory. Changing the data of the maps doesn't change the data of the vector.

Comment: It's not quite that the vector contains pointers to maps. It's that each map contains pointers to the actual data, to nodes that it allocates on the heap.

Comment: I'm sure someone can write a detailed answer, now, after the problem is clear. I'm not so good at these topics

Comment: Think of something simple like `vector<string> strings(10);`. You can `strings[0] = read_war_and_peace();` without changing the size of `strings` from 10 elements. Each of the 10 `string`s in `strings` is its own `string` with its own buffer of data and they all can represent wildly different amounts of data.

Comment: Important note that Igor's hinting at is every data structure in C++ has a size fixed at compile time. It can never change. It may contain a pointer or reference to other data and the size of that other data can change. A `unordered_map` at its simplest is a pointer to an array and a couple book-keeping variables tracking stuff like the array capacity. The pointed at array can be replaced with a larger or smaller array (but the array itself can never change size) without changing the size of the `unordered_map`

Comment: Why is this? if objects in an array can change size `array[index]` suddenly gets extremely complicated. You can't just advance `index` times 42 to get the indexth element. You'd have to find the size of the first object, advance that many bytes to find the second object. Then get the size of that object and advance size bytes to find the third. Repeat `index` times. Murderously slow. Sometimes you need to pack an array like this to save space or because you're serializing it to send to a file or over a network, but in the computer's memory, waste the space and take advantage of the speed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything banned to be done in multiple threads in your code.

Now, proving this is *hard*, as any part of the standard could in theory add "and a line looking like that is a race condition".

But I can tell you the simple rule of thumb.

1. Two threads can access the same `std` container so long as the methods used are `const`.
2. A single thread accessing a `std` container in any way does not generate a race condition.
3. You can access different elements *in* a std container from different threads without causing a race condition.
4. For the purpose of rule 1, "lookup" operations that don't create new elements count as `const`.  These are stuff like `.find` on associative containers, and `[]` on `std::vector`, but not `[]` on `std::map`.
5. Any kind of iterator invalidation is a race condition with basically anything.

these rules aren't complete.  But you'll note you don't break any of them.

In short, you can read/write from one member of a vector freely from one thread, while another thread reads/writes in another.  Just don't reallocate memory (invalidate an iterator) or have one thread write while another reads the same member.

Comment: There's a list of methods in cppreference `vector` that invalidates references. See [this under "Iterator invalidation"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) Any of these mess up the OP's multithreading but none are used.